# Umbraco Content Root node not showing the tree-like expandable navigation structure

Tags: umbraco7, umbraco-mvc

I have an Umbraco site for which I created an root node and child elements underneath it. The pages are there and I can find them in the 'Child items' tab, but I don't get the tree-like navigation in the admin content view. Is there some way to enable this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like to have list view enabled on your document type.  If you go back to the Settings section,  navigate to the document type of your root node and click on the Structure tab you should see an 'Enable list view' option.  Un-check this and the child items will appear in the tree.

You could also create your own tab called 'Child items' and then add a property of type 'List view'.  This way you'll be able to have the content tree and list view active at the same time.

Comment: Robert, how do you add a property of type 'List View'? I don't see that option. Thanks for your help!

Comment: First you might need to create a list view Data Type.  To do this go to the Developer section, right click on the Data Types folder and select Create.  Enter 'List view' as the name, select the 'List view' option in the Property editor drop drown list and click save.  The List view option should then appear as one of the options when you go to add a new property.